# tfs check-in project wants to delete file

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I am not sure how this happen I want to check-in the project sln but it wants to include a delete. If I filter pending changes it displays this file but I dont want to delete it I want to keep it and add the lock. When I try to undo I get a message the file must be deleted.

> Is there anyway around this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there are someone deleted files but affected and did a "`tf delete`" on this `.aspx` file.

For solve this, please try with follow steps:

- First, rename this file(ListOfDrug.aspx) to something else (ie
  NewListDrug.aspx)
- Undo pending delete of packages.config
- Checkout packages.config from TFS
- Delete packages.config from fileSystem
- Rename newpackages.config back to packages.config

I know this may painful, especially affects many different projects at the same time. But this seem be the useful way to solve this issue.